# Installing iOS app with iTunes has no image

Tags: ios, ios5, icons, itunes, ad-hoc-distribution

I create an app for distribution with ad-hoc, but when i drop it into iTunes there is no image. Then we i drop the app to the device there is still now image. I must be missing a step somewhere.

I have the images in the correct places with Xcode, but still no dice.

**UPDATE**

This is in reponse to Sergio
[image]

Comment: you mean the icon? or what image?

Comment: @sergio the icon that appears on the screen. the little 57 x 57 launch icon the user clicks to enter the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking that the .plist file in your project has got the correct settings for the app icon. E.g. (image)

[image]

Keep also in mind that on one occasion at least I had the experience of the app icon not showing and the only thing I could come up with was the fact that the icon had a custom name (e.g. myapp-icon). reverting the icon name to "Icon.png" everything went ok.

Comment: I added a screen shot above that looks like it is setup correctly.

Comment: So you were actually right. I removed all the images from Xcode and then put them back in one by one. Worked like a snake charm. Thanks for icon.png tip.